# Does upgrading iOS change my IMEI?

Tags: iphone, ios, sim

Does upgrading iOS change my IMEI? I was told not by AT&T not to remove my SIM card or certain restrictions that they had placed on the iPhone, at my request, would be lifted. I want to know if upgrading my iOS is like removing the SIM card. I think this was because the IMEI number changes when the SIM card is removed from the phone.

Does upgrading iOS change this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IMEI is kind of like a MAC address for the cellular network only. It is nearly impossible to change it, you can only spoof it on a software level. So the answer is, **No, your IMEI will never change** unless you really really want it to. Removing the SIM card shouldn't change the IMEI either...

Answer (score 3):

The IMEI shouldn’t change when you upgrade the phone, at least here in Europe. Mine is still the same.

**Update**: Upon some reading around, it turns out that if you “hack” your phone, (maybe in the past), an update would change some IMEIs, and AT&T would therefore invalidate the SIM. Be careful with what you do :)

Comment: I'm in the US. I'm going to go with you on this one. I'll select this answer if and when it proves accurate. I need to perform the upgrade first.

Comment: @Moshe Good luck! (You might want to clarify the grammar in the first sentence. “I’m asking because I was told not by AT&T not to remove my SIM…” Sounds weird. They told you not to remove the SIM…is that correct? Why do you want to remove the SIM?

Comment: Edited. better?

Comment: @Moshe I believe the part that is not clear is if you were told by AT&T not to remove the sim or you were “told not by AT&T”. In essence, did they tell you NOT to remove it or… the DIDN’T tell you to NOT remove it? Ahh… logic.

Answer (score 2):

No, upgrading the OS doesnt change the IMEI by default, there are hacks available to do it, but its illegal and hence, not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

No. Upgrading iOS won't change the IMEI of your iPhone.